# Summing up float number loses precision with type conversion

Tags: c++

I tried to add two digits with different weights. Here is my code:

```
void onTimeStepOp::updatePointsType1_2(boost::tuples::tuple<float,int,int,int> &_prev,
                                     boost::tuples::tuple<float,int,int,int> &_result,
                                       boost::tuples::tuple<float,float> weights)
{
    _result.get<0>() = _result.get<0>() * weights.get<0>() + _prev.get<0>() * weights.get<1>();
    std::cout<<"deb:"<<(float)_result.get<2>() * weights.get<0>()<<" "<<(float)_prev.get<2>() * weights.get<1>()<<std::endl;
    _result.get<2>() = (int)((float)(_result.get<2>()) * weights.get<0>() + (float)(_prev.get<2>()) * weights.get<1>());
    std::cout<<"deb2:"<<(float)_result.get<3>() * weights.get<0>() <<" "<< (float)_prev.get<3>() * weights.get<1>()<<std::endl;
    _result.get<3>() = (int)((float)(_result.get<3>()) * weights.get<0>() + (float)(_prev.get<3>()) * weights.get<1>());
}
```

weights.get<0> = 0.3,weights.get<1> = 0.7.

The output I get looks like this:

```
resultBefore=36.8055 4 69 91 previousPPos=41.192 4 69 91
deb:20.7 48.3
deb2:27.3 63.7
resultAfter=39.8761 4 **68** 91
```

The third number should be 69(69 * 0.3 + 69 * 0.7). However, it is 68 instead. What's the problem with the type conversion expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion to `int` truncates, so the slightest rounding error could cause you to be one off.  Rather than converting directly to `int`, you might want to use the function `round`.

I might add that `weights.get<0>` is certainly *not* 0.3, and `weights.get<1>` is certainly not 0.7, since neither 0.3 nor 0.7 are representable in machine floating point (at least not on any machine you're likely to be using).

Answer (score 0):

You should `round()` instead of just casting to `int`. Casting trims everything after the decimal point, and the number due to rounding error may be something like `68.99999999991` (just an example but gives the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `int` will result the number before the dot, so `68.1..68.9` will be all `68` as written before.
Another solution could be, which is not so nice, that is to add `0.5` to your `float` value before casting. So `68.1` will be `68.6`, which will be still `68`, but `68.5` will be `69` which will be `69`.